# Как решить данную задачу на C++?

Tags: c++, методы, структуры, аргументы

Текст задачи:
Напишите структуру ThisChecker.
У неё будет всего один метод bool IsSame(const ThisChecker&). Т.е. метод принимает только один аргумент, константную ссылку на объект типа ThisChecker.
Этот метод должен вернуть true, если аргументом является тот же самый объект, метод которого вызывается, и false в противном случае (см. пример).
Метод должен работать как для константных, так и не константных объектов(также см. пример)
В систему отправляйте только код структуры

Пример:

```
    ThisChecker a;
    ThisChecker b;
    std::cout << a.IsSame(b) << "\n"; // false
    std::cout << a.IsSame(a) << "\n"; // true
    const ThisChecker& c = a;
    std::cout << c.IsSame(a) << "\n"; // true
```

У меня написан небольшой код, он выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ThisChecker {
    bool IsSame(const ThisChecker&t) {
        if (&t == this) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        };
    }
};

int main(){
    ThisChecker a, b, c;
    std::cout << a.IsSame(a);
    std::cout << b.IsSame(a); 
    std::cout << b.IsSame(b);
    const ThisChecker& c = a;
    std::cout << c.IsSame(a) << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Я никак не могу взять в толк - каким способом я могу взаимодействовать с объектом и аргументом внутри выполнения метода, чтобы анализировать их идентичность, или различие. Думаю, на них как-то нужно оставить ссылку, но сделать это, как ни пытался, не знаю как.

Кроме того, код не работает с константными объектами

Я сам начинающий - спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Спасибо, я постарался исправить вопрос

Comment: ОК, теперь вполне нормально.

Comment: Ваш код вообще не должен компилироваться - в нем вы сначала объявляете `ThisChecker a, b, c;`, а потом с тем же именем `const ThisChecker& c = a;`

Comment: Да, лишнее объявление "c" проставил здесь. Но я это уже исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
bool ThisChecker::IsSame(const ThisChecker& t) const {
    return &t == this;
    }
```

Возможно, от вас хотят именно этого решения. Не "точно такой же", а "именно тот же".

Comment: Спасибо. Я подумал, что формулировка задачи будет выглядеть объемно, а код фактически не несёт никакого смысла. Мысли я попытался изложить, сейчас, попробую подправить вопрос. В код я попробовал это подставить, вставил как предложили вы, и используя if else для контроля вывода, но код не работает с константными объектами. Но спасибо! я попробую сам додумать по этому поводу

Comment: Добавьте еще один `const`, я исправил ответ.

Comment: Да, все заработало! Огромное спасибо, не подскажете какую тему стоит изучить, чтобы под тянуть этот материал? Я так понимаю это "классы и структуры" + "ссылки"?

Comment: Да даже не скажу, что именно, смотрите просто учебники полностью, а не отрывочно, наверное, так.